# How is pouchdb website so fast ? What caching mechanism used on the website

Tags: performance, caching, browser-cache, pagespeed, http-caching

Just a random question but would like to know the underlying caching technique.

How is [pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/) website **https://pouchdb.com/** so fast, on the first request it takes time to load but after that when we navigate to different links it is pretty fast.

what kind of browser caching or any other caching is implemented here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PouchDB website installs a serviceWorker that does basic caching of static assets and pages + a few of the first blog posts

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/master/docs/serviceWorker.js